# Cannot add component of type:CustomObject to another package because it is an installed component

Tags: salesforcedx, deployment, error, package, namespace

I created a package and now I want to create a dependent package. Let's say the parent package has a custom object: `namespace__Application__c`

In my child package, under the objects directory, I have:
`namespace__Application__c/fields/`

which is a directory of *new* fields to be added to the object.

When I try to install the package, I get the following error:

> package.xml: Cannot add component of type:CustomObject named:namespace__Application__c subjectId:01IP0000000Iz59 to another package because it is an installed component.

The parent package is already installed and the child package gets compiled with no errors, but this happens when I try to install it.

I can only find one more result [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/262579/cannot-add-component-to-another-package-because-it-is-an-installed-component) but it's a different problem.

Details about the environment:

1. Both packages are attached to the same dev hub
2. Both packages created with this command: `sfdx force:package:version:create --package PackageName --path force-app --installationkey XXXXX --wait 10 --definitionfile config/project-scratch-def.json`
3. I'm trying to install them to a temporary scratch org - the parent package installs fine, the child package fails

Here's the `sfdx-project.json`

````
    "packageDirectories": [
        {
            "path": "force-app",
            "default": true,
            "package": "ChildPackage",
            "versionName": "ver 0.2",
            "versionNumber": "0.2.0.NEXT",
            "dependencies": [
                {
                    "package": "ParentPackage@0.1.0-9"
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "namespace": "namespace",
    "sfdcLoginUrl": "https://login.salesforce.com",
    "sourceApiVersion": "47.0",
    "packageAliases": {
        "ChildPackage": "0HoXXX",
        "ParentPackage@0.1.0-9": "04tXXX",
        ... multiple versions of ChildPackage ...
        "ChildPackage@0.1.0-15": "04tXXX"
    }
}```
````

Comment: What are the orgs involved here - where are you trying to install this second package? Are you using 1GP or 2GP?

Comment: @DavidReed I believe it's 2GP - it's an unlocked package. Added more details in the main post

Comment: What's your sfdx-project.json file look like? Did you *actually* list the parent package as a dependency?

Comment: @sfdcfox I updated the post with the sfdx-project.json

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your 2GP packages, you need to use the name/versionNumber format for your dependencies:

```
"dependencies": [
    {
        "package": "ParentPackage",
        "versionNumber": "0.1.0.LATEST"
    }
]
```

It took me a little while to figure this out myself.

Also, make sure you do *not* have an object-meta.xml file in the root of each object folder for the child packages. It should contain only field metadata.

Comment: Wow, you are right! It seemed to have worked. I would have never caught that. Thank you!